# implementing PUT method of restful web services in javascript

Tags: jersey, webservice-client, restful-url

I am developing a RESTful web service using NetBeans, GlassFish server and MySQL as the backend. I want to create a RESTful web service client using JavaScript which will consume all services through it. I already have created a client that implements the `GET`, `POST` and `DELETE` methods. However, I'd like to implement the `PUT` method in JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty much a matter of changing type specification on the client side - but you may have to write some client or server-side logic (e.g. upper-casing or lower casing before evaluation, as part of your input sanitizing), depending on your support parameters. See the link at the end for more details.

---

With jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    url: restfulPutUrl,
    type: "PUT"
}).done(function() {
    $(this).addClass("done");
});
```

see [jQuery docs](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/), especially:

> Other HTTP request methods, such as PUT and DELETE, can also be used [with the type parameter], but they are not supported by all browsers.

---

Without:

```
 function createXMLHttpRequest() {
   try { return new XMLHttpRequest(); } catch(e) {}
   try { return new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP"); } catch (e) {}
   alert("XMLHttpRequest not supported");
   return null;
 }

 var xhReq = createXMLHttpRequest();
 xhReq.open("PUT", "restfulPutUrl", true);
```

see [ajaxpatterns.org](http://ajaxpatterns.org/XMLHttpRequest_Call#Creating_XMLHttpRequest_Objects) if needed

---

PUT is not implemented uniformly, http://annevankesteren.nl/2007/10/http-method-support for more details.